# Capture an argument passed to function in different JavaScript file using Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have a JavaScript file `main_one.js` which requires another JavaScript file `helper.js`.

helper.js

```
warp = {
  postThisEvent: function(a) {
    // some operation on a
  }
};
```

main_one.js

```
var Helper = require('path/helper.js');
// some steps
Helper.warp.postThisEvent(event);
```

I want to capture `event` using Jasmine. How do I create my spy object for capturing `event` in `postThisEvent()`?

Comment: Do you want to do anything with `event`, or just prove that it has been called with `event`? What are you trying to prove in the test? Are you using event for anything in the test?

Comment: The event is being sent to external code. The event has a number of properties. I want to check that all the required properties are set before sending the event.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the Jasmine test require `Helper`, then spy this way:

```
spyOn(Helper.warp, "postThisEvent").and.callThrough();
```

This will replace `postThisEvent` on the object `Helper.warp` with a spy function. When it's called the spy will register the call and than call the original method as this was instructed by `callThrough()`.

Then you can expect that `postThisEvent()` was called with the expected objects this way:

```
expect(Helper.warp.postThisEvent).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.objectContaining({
    someProperty: "someValue"
}));
```

`jasmine.objectContaining()` is a helper that will only test that the expecte properties are present among multiple properties of the object under test.

You can also inspect complex objects directly:

```
expect(Helper.warp.postThisEvent.calls.mostRecent().args[0].someProperty).toBe("someValue");
```

Note that such a spy might not work when `postThisEvent()` was saved to a variable which is then called like this:

```
var postThisEvent = Helper.warp.postThisEvent;
function triggering() {
    postThisEvent({ someProperty: "someValue" })
}
// now a spy is created and then triggering() is called
```

In this case the reference to the original method cannot be reached when spying. There's no way to intercept the function/method in this case in Javascript.

See

- [Jasmine 2.4 Spies](http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html#section-Spies) and
- Spy inspection in the chapter [Other tracking properties](http://jasmine.github.io/2.4/introduction.html#section-Other_tracking_properties)